# nginx - browser can't stop directing to https?

Tags: ssl, nginx, archlinux

Why nginx keep on directing without instructions?

I followed this [guide](https://www.ghostforbeginners.com/how-to-proxy-port-80-to-2368-for-ghost-with-nginx/) to redirect port 80 to 3000:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.co.uk www.example.co.uk;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    }
}
```

It worked fine. Then I tried to roll back as before, and it just keeps on redirecting to https!

I even have removed nginx, but the browser is still redirecting to https! Why? What have done wrong? How can I fix it?

Any ideas?

This was the config before I tried on the redirect thingy:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.co.uk www.example.co.uk;
     return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
      # listen       80;
      listen 433 ssl;
      server_name  example.co.uk www.example.co.uk;

      ssl on;
      ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.co.uk/fullchain.pem;
      ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.co.uk/privkey.pem;

      #charset koi8-r;

      #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

      location / {
          root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
          index  index.html index.htm;
     }

      location ~ /.well-known {
              allow all;
      }
```

the HTTPS was working fine to before that.

EDIT:

I have re-installed nginx and tested it with `nginx -t`:

```
$ sudo nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

Comment: The usual reason a browser redirects to `https` without consulting the server is because of a historical HSTS header. It can be difficult to make some browsers forget an HSTS header.

Comment: @RichardSmith I have removed my browser histories. Any ideas what I can do?

Comment: Confirm the problem by using a different browser. Also, have you tested the server configuration using `nginx -t`?

Comment: @RichardSmith it happens on different browsers - Firefox, Opera, Chrome. they all have the same https redirection. I didn't check with `nginx -t` but everything was working fine until i rolled back.

Comment: @RichardSmith please see my edit above. thanks.

Comment: I am confused as to which configuration you are currently using. `nginx -T` will test the configuration **and** print it out.

Comment: @RichardSmith i got it fixed after re-installing and abandoning 433 port. it is broken for some reasons...

Comment: Erm, shouldn't that be port 443?

Comment: @RichardSmith aww my bad! lol